Segmentation Fault when Running pip install with Pyenv on macOS M1
I’m encountering a segmentation fault while trying to install Python packages with pip inside a pyenv-managed environment on my macOS M1 system.
Steps I Followed:
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.10.0
pyenv global 3.10.0
pip install transformers
Error I am getting
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pyenv/2.4.16/pyenv.d/exec/pip-rehash/pip: line 20: 20306 Segmentation fault: 11  "$PYENV_COMMAND_PATH" "$@"
I tried reinstalling pyenv and python, but it didn't work.

You need to do something like pyenv global 3.10.0; pip install transformers to use the virtual environment you created.

I already tried that. but still the same.

First, if you had installed pyenv-virtualenv as a plugin; remove that from the folder and try installing it through homebrew using brew install pyenv-virtualenv. If not fixed, this is what I did:
This might sound like quite an arbitrary answer, but as you can read in this closed Issue, there are several suggestions, I tried some of them but this one was the one that worked for me
After I reinstalled my homebrew things got fixed.
Just be careful by uninstalling homebrew you might need to reinstall and fix so many softwares.
My steps:

Uninstall pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv using brew uninstall pyenv-virtualenv
Uninstall homebrew using its uninstall script.
(Optional) As I was using fish terminal i had to fix that issue separately as well by opening up a zsh then doing brew install fish.
Installing pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv using brew install pyenv-virtualenv
Then again I had an other error saying Failed to activate virtualenv. in which I followed this and got fixed.



In other tickets, Segmentation faults happened for MacOS users when they had migrated a Homebrew installation onto a new major MacOS version which it wasn't compatible with (each major MacOS release gets its own build of Homebrew libraries).
In this case, one needs to reinstall Homebrew, then reinstall all Pyenv-managed Python versions so that they are rebuilt against the new libs.

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1048#issuecomment-1696391886
